# Speed ​query update mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have to update about 400 records of a table placed on an online mysql DB containing about 1500 records.
I executed a cycle with an UPDATE query at each cycle, but the update times are about 1 minute.
Advise me how I could speed up the update.

Note:
- I have already indexed the table;
- the code is in C #;

Comment: Can you add more information about the table, the fields, the C# code, etc?

Comment: Updating a single row in a table should not require a minute.  Updating 400 rows should not require a minute.  More information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generate Dynamic query string for that ended with semicolon for each cycle**

Example :

```
string sqlQuery = null; // Or use StringBuilder for better memory performance
foreach(var cycle in Cycles){
  // Your scenario gone here
   sqlQuery += "UPDATE YourTable SET Columns = Values ; \n";
}
```

Previous Code Will just executes all update statements together ! **Batch Update**

I Use dynamic string generation when working with BLOBs or many queries generated from cycle or controls or etc.. that updated together in single statement will be fast .

```
   // BLOBS
    if (Configuration.StoreObjectsAsBinary)
    {
        foreach (var BLOB in BLOBS)
          CommandText += $"INSERT INTO General.BLOB(SystemID, BinaryValue) 
                           VALUES({SystemID} {BLOB.Value}); \n";
    }
 // Note the  Escapse character is important, and semicolon is must or try your luck.
```

Use [Dapper](http://Install-Package%20Dapper%20-Version%202.0.30) ORM for better performance or execution query

Or Legacy ADO.NET for maintainability and readability

```
using(var conection = new SqlConnection(""))
{ 
   connection.Open();
   using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE QUERY", connection))
   {
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    // Or better use Async version with await
   }
}
```

Note that using statement is important for make connection back again to [ConnectionPooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

Comment: Excellent, reduced time to a few seconds.
Thanks